# Lusternik-Schnirelmann Theorem

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, critical-point-theory

In various paper i found this: 
[image]

But i don't find this theorem of Lusternik-Schnirelmann, have you an idea where i can find this theorem, the condition?

Thank you.

Comment: From what paper is the screenshot?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/dhiZd.png

Comment: I think this paper may help you: James, I. M. "[The Lusternik-Schnirelmann theorem reconsidered.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/016686419290094G)" Topology and its Applications 44.1 (1992): 197-202.

Comment: Try section 2.7 of  these notes  http://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/Morse2nd.pdf Theorems 2.7.6 and 2.7.10 in that section contain the answer to your question.

Comment: Thank you but in the theorem 2.7.10 there is no PS condition

Comment: On compact manifolds (like in Thm 2.7.10) the PS-Smale condition is automatically satisfied.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu please can you help me in this question please: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1126738/question-about-computing-a-complicated-integral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check the paper

Palais, Richard S.
*Lusternik-Schnirelman theory on Banach manifolds.* 
Topology 5 1966 115–132.

See also Theorem 1.15 of

Cornea, Octav; Lupton, Gregory; Oprea, John; Tanré, Daniel
*Lusternik-Schnirelmann category.* 
Mathematical Surveys and Monographs, 103. American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 2003.

The relevant chapter is available to view on [Google Books](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=vMREfNN-L4gC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: In cornea do you know what is the theorem ? i found one in Chang's book but the is the condition bounded from below but in this paper they don't prove that the functional is bounded from below

Comment: See my edit for a more precise reference.

Comment: theorem 1.15 right ?

Comment: Yes, Theorem 1.15.

Comment: Mark Grant please have you an idea why $\beta\circ \phi_{\varepsilon}$ is homotopic to the identity map, and why this fact give that $cat_{\tilde{N_{\varepsilon}}}\tilde{N_{\varepsilon}}\geq cat_{M_{\delta}}M$ please Thank you

Comment: @Vrouvrou: I'm not sure what you are asking, can you give a page reference?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/dhiZd.png page 1309